# How do I know if I need a Manifest for .NET application for UAC purposes?

Tags: .net, uac

Are there rules or guidelines to know whether a .NET application manifest is needed for UAC purposes?

I have an application that writes to the registry (HKLM > Software > yadda yadda) and performs file I/O.  I'm not sure if it needs manifest for this or not.  The file I/O may be to a network share (although, the app itself prompts the user for credentials) or locally.

I'd rather not just set it to the max level if I'm unsure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include a manifest.  If you don't want to always request elevation you don't have to, you can ask for asInvoker or highestAvailable. If your app doesn't run without elevation you may simply have no choice, apart from changing the app of course.

I found a couple of sites very handy when trying to learn this stuff.

This site has a great explanation of how UAC works and how you can expect it to affect your applications:

*What Every Software Engineer Must Know About Windows Vista*
http://codefromthe70s.org/vistatutorial.aspx

I also found this blog post about manifests useful:

*Answers to Several Application Manifest Mysteries and Questions*
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2009/12/09/answers-to-several-application-manifest-mysteries-and-questions.aspx

As for your specific case, the best thing is just to try it. If you're able to write to the registry keys you need and to the disk without elevation then you can leave it set to asInvoker.

As long as you're not trying to save anything to a restricted area (like the System directory) the I/O should not pose a problem.  I'm afraid I can't remember the rules on writing to HKLM\Software.  If it works without elevation, great.

But I would still include a manifest as a matter of best practices.